# Loader while filtering data with keywords

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I want to show a loader when I search properties with the filter method. When somebody searches it should show a loading spinner when the filter is complete it should show the data.. I'm not filtering data with API calls. I have used react hooks for a loading state and it is true by default. If anyone can help me how can I use the setState hook inside a function to change the state, if I use setState in the function it will re-render again and again which is not allowed .if anyone of you can help please help

```js
export const applyFilters = (properties, query) => {
  return (
    properties &&
    properties.filter((property, i) => {
      let matches = true;

      if (query) {
        const keys = ["title"];
        let containsQuery = false;

        keys.forEach(key => {
          if (property[key].toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
            containsQuery = true;
          }
        });

        if (!containsQuery) {
          matches = false;
        }
      }

      return matches;
    })
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filtering is a synchronous operation so it should be almost instantaneous.  I would not show a spinner at all.

Generally I recommend that the filter itself should be a state. That would be your `query` variable.  But the filtered data should just be a variable derived from the states (or props) of `query` and `properties`.

```
export const FilterProperties = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  // some state that gets set somehow, or maybe properties is a prop
  const [properties, setProperties] = useState([]);

  const filteredProperties = applyFilters(properties, query);

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={query} onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
      <ul>
        {filteredProperties.map((property) => (
          <li key={property.id}>{property.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you are concerned about performance then you can use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to re-compute the `filteredProperties` variable only when `query` or `properties` changes.

```
const filteredProperties = useMemo(
  () => applyFilters(properties, query), 
  [properties, query]
);
```

---

The filter function itself can be cleaned up quite a bit.  We can use default arguments instead of checking that `properties` and `query` exist.  We can use an empty array for `properties` to return no matches and an empty string for `query` which matches everything.

If you always just want to search the `title` then this `keys` array is pointless:

```
const applyFilters = (properties = [], query = "") =>
    properties.filter((property) =>
        property.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
    );
```

But we can make `keys` an argument to allow more customization.  We make use of the [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to see if any of the keys are a match.

```
const applyFilters = (properties = [], query = "", keys = ["title"]) =>
    properties.filter((property) =>
        // true if any key contains the query
        keys.some((key) =>
            property[key].toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
        )
    );
```